# Configure tex4ht for colortbl and tabulary

Tags: tex4ht, colortbl

I'm trying to use `colortbl` together with `tex4ht`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabulary,colortbl}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{C}
test\\
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

When calling htlatex.bat, the result is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\begin:current@color ->\let \sv:curcolor
                                     \current@color
l.4 \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{C}
```

I assume that tex4ht needs some more "configuration" (as Eitan always put it). How is this configuration done?

I'm using SVN revision 88 from the tex4ht-SVN: http://svn.gnu.org.ua/sources/tex4ht/trunk/.

htlatex.bat is from: http://svn.gnu.org.ua/sources/tex4ht/trunk/bin/ht/win32/htlatex.bat

Comment: could you please post the content of htlatex.bat , I tried your MWE on Windows 7 / MikteX and could not reproduce the error.

Comment: See the same error with TeX Live 2012, so I suspect this is an issue tex4ht.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in `tex4ht`: I see the problematic behaviour with TeX Live 2012 and TeX Live 2013. As such, the best that can be done is to report it formally: I will.

Comment: Reported as https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?187